# D3 transitions behave strangely in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, transition

I have a simple circle transition in D3, i have about 23 different circles with unique names and they move from point A to point B. I'm using "circle name" as the key in .data().

Everything works fine in internet explorer but when i try it in Chrome, the bubbles do not map correctly. For example, bubble 1 becomes the color and "r" of bubble 3 as the transition runs. Final positions are correct, the bubbles end up where they're supposed to be but they all mix (fill and "r") in between the two points.

Code below:

```
 g.selectAll("circle").data(effedate, function (d) { return d.BubbleName; }).enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x_scale(d.PercentageComplete * 100) })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y_scale(d.GPoS * 100) })
      .attr("r", function (d) { return r_scale(d.MSVMMboe) })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("opacity", 0.6)
      .attr("fill", function (d) {
          if (d.FairWay == "A") {
              return "steelblue";
          }
          else if (d.FairWay == "B") {
              return "yellow";
          }
          else if (d.FairWay == "C") {
              return "lightgreen";
          }
          else {
              return "lightblue";
          }
      });

      g.selectAll('circle')
             .data(effedate).exit().remove();

      //transition
      g.selectAll("circle").data(effedate2, function (d) { return d.BubbleName; }).transition().duration(3000)
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x_scale(d.PercentageComplete * 100) })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y_scale(d.GPoS * 100) })
      .attr("r", function (d) { return r_scale(d.MSVMMboe) })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("opacity", 0.6)
      .attr("fill", function (d) {
          if (d.FairWay == "A") {
              return "steelblue";
          }
          else if (d.FairWay == "B") {
              return "yellow";
          }
          else if (d.FairWay == "C") {
              return "lightgreen";
          }
          else {
              return "lightblue";
          }
      });
```

Has anyone experience problems with transitions in google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds kinda odd and unlikely that Chrome is at fault. More likely that the problem is with the mapping of data to elements. Still, your code looks mostly fine from here.

One thing is wrong though:

```
g.selectAll('circle')
    .data(effedate).exit().remove();// <- WRONG: missing function (d) { return d.BubbleName; }
```

You need to supply the key function to return `d.BubbleName`.

iF that doesn't fix it: Are you sure `d.BubbleName` is yielding the right values? Did you `console.log` it from within the function where it's used?

Also, could there be other `svg:circle`s in the same group `g` that are throwing off your selectAll.